# Change detection and Material 2

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design, angular-material

In my [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/F2loNWRPc8cYGjW6zygW?p=preview) I have a parent component with two buttons and one input field. The first button will set a flag to show a child component, that will get the form group of the parent element. It adds another input field to this form group with a "required" validation.

The second button is configured to be "disabled" if the used form group is not valid:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <input type="text" [formControl]="formGroup.get('nameParent')" />
      <child *ngIf="show===true" [inputform]="formGroup"></child>
      <button (click)="addChild()">Add child</button>
      <button [disabled]="!formGroup.valid" md-raised-button>Valid</button>
</form>
```

The second button has the md-raised-button directive, that transforms it to a material button. 
If you type something in the input field, the raised button will turn enabled. If you push the "Add child" button *after* you typed something you will get an error in the console:

> Error in app.component.html:4:14 caused by: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

But wait:
If you now remove the md-raised-button from the button to use it as a native control, the same experiment will succeed *without* the error message.
Ergo: The material design component seems to do something that causes this to happen. Any ideas:

1. Why this happens?
2. How I could get rid of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because clicking the button fires an event which causes to have the `formGroup` to be triggered, and setting the disabled property on the second button to `true`. This all happens inside a change detection cycle, which means a value is changed within the cycle. This is usually a sign of bad practice. You can think of using a different structure or implementing the `ChangeDetectionRef` and `detectChanges` after you set the change:

*Only showing relevant code*

```
private show: boolean;

constructor(private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

addChild() {
  this.show = true;
  this.changeRef.detectChanges();
}
```

[working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/mDl0dr4ulhSzSW7gbv37?p=preview)

Comment: Cool! And any idea why it worked without the md-raised-button? :) And shouldn't the mouse event itself not already start a change detection?

Comment: Probably md-raised triggers something internally based on the disabled property. This is what caused that loop. And yes, the mouse event does trigger the change detection, but within that, another change occurred. It's a complex thing, which me myself sometimes have a hard time wrapping my head around it